# random number generation in C++ within a range

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, numbers

I have a question where I have to generate random numbers with following condition
     1) number should be b/w 0 and 1.

2) numbers are produced in equally likely manner

let's say I have a number x eg 0.0028. If I call this random number generator 10000 times then it should produce numbers less than x to be 28. How can this be achieved. Does someone have any idea. I tried to use various distributions but was not successful in achieving the desired result.

Comment: Please show us, what you already tried. In c++11 you also have all the required distributions.

Comment: Clarify this question, because I can honestly say I personally haven't a clue what "... then it should produce numbers less than x to be 28." even means.

Comment: I have tried uniform_real_distribution as show below. There was large variation in results from actual results when the fractional part is small.  Well @WhozCraig I wanted to build a random number generator which can produce numbers according to number x which I will input. On running the generator 10000 times the numbers less then x should be x*10000

Comment: @user2033594: That's not how random generators (or pseudo-random generators) work. You will get normally distributed results around the expected value 10000·x, but usually not the exact value. Your requirement is like saying: I'm going to roll this dice six times and if it doesn't show each number only once, it must be crooked.

Comment: @Oehm Unfortunately I have the same use case

Comment: Perhaps you can share the acutal use case. It looks as if random numbers aren't the answer to your actual problem.

Comment: This is very unclear.  Are you asking how to generate values so that their **sum**  should be exactly 28?  If not, in what way should generating values between 0 and 1 yield 28?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a uniform distribution random number generator. This is the example from the [C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/):

Edit: [Link to cppreference which contains another example.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

It produces the result I understood you need, but more details in the question would help a lot.

```
// uniform_real_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  const int nrolls=10000;  // number of experiments
  const int nstars=95;     // maximum number of stars to distribute
  const int nintervals=10; // number of intervals

  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

  int p[nintervals]={};

  for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
    double number = distribution(generator);
    ++p[int(nintervals*number)];
  }

  std::cout << "uniform_real_distribution (0.0,1.0):" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::fixed; std::cout.precision(1);

  for (int i=0; i<nintervals; ++i) {
    std::cout << float(i)/nintervals << "-" << float(i+1)/nintervals << ": ";
    std::cout << std::string(p[i]*nstars/nrolls,'*') << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As i said I have used this distribution and i am not getting the desired result

Comment: Side note: In general, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) usually is better choice for citations, cplusplus.com sometimes is outdated or even contains errors...

Comment: @Aconcagua I added a reference from cppreference as well. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @user2033594: distribution seems correct,  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9670f569ba12492) you have around 28 numbers below target.

Comment: @jarod42 there have been cases where the generated numbers are very off. It is because of the decimal factor that numbers are not correct. Is there a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about the random numbers generation concept is a little wrong. The random number generator algorithms are designed to ensure an almost equal chance of selection of any number in their specified range. However, they never guarantee to provide uniform distribution in all of their produced sequences of numbers.
Here, you also did not specify the type of random number you have generated. If it was double, it might produce some inaccuracies due to the huge range of possible numbers. Maybe trying with random integer numbers instead can acceptably solve your problem.